# New line as a separator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have following code to get lines with string i need

```
import pyscp
f = open("base.txt", "r")
searchlines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "смерть" in line: 
        for l in searchlines[i: i+3]: print(l)
```

For example, i am searching for "смерть"
It gives me following

```
SCP-1056-RU-V - Жизнь и смерть

SCP-1056-RU - Творческие метания

SCP-2061 - Целая местная семья подавилась насмерть одним калькулятором

SCP-2062 - Кронекер

SCP-2668 - Идущие на смерть приветствуют тебя!

SCP-2669 - Кебтеул 1

SCP-510 - Мягкая смерть

SCP-5115 - Не от мира сего

SСP-3984 - Потыкай в смерть палочкой

SСP-4220 - Темная сторона Луны
```

I want to make list like this
[scp-xxx--ejdj, scp-xxxx-jddj...]
So i need to use new line as a separator, how can i do that?
linesplite doesn't work here.

Comment: I think you should do it in template

Comment: What do you mean by template?

Comment: Why a newline? If you want a list of SCP IDs, split each line by space and append the ID to a list.

Comment: That is a question, what separator i should use in split() to do that?

Comment: str.split("\n") also didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split()` and firs value is your `SCP-xxx` variable:

```py
f = open("your_file.txt", "r")
searchlines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()] # <-- skip empty lines
f.close()

out = []
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "смерть" in line:
        for l in searchlines[i : i + 3]:
            out.append(l.split(maxsplit=1)[0])  # <-- add to out the first value

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['SCP-1056-RU-V', 'SCP-1056-RU', 'SCP-2061', 'SCP-2061', 'SCP-2062', 'SCP-2668', 'SCP-2668', 'SCP-2669', 'SCP-510', 'SCP-510', 'SCP-5115', 'SСP-3984', 'SСP-3984', 'SСP-4220']
```

Comment: That works, thank you, will accept answer in 4 min

Comment: Skipping empty lines seems redundant, because none of them will have `"смерть"` in them anyway, and stripping won't affect the result of `split()`.

Comment: @bereal You have right, but I prefer to work with clean data (and it's not much work anyway).